# IntelliJ IDEA 13 community edition with Scala

Tags: java, scala, intellij-idea

I have IntelliJIDEA 13 installed on my windows 8 OS and would like to use it to develop Scala applications. However, I am unable to configure it. I have Scala version 2.10.3 installed and IntelliJ IDEA 13.0.1. I also have Java version 7 update 45.

I installed the scala plugin for IntelliJ, but whenever I start the application and try to make a new Scala module project I get the following window with an error "not valid scala home":

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lOyoe.png

Comment: Can you try path to Scala home without spaces? E.g. C:\scala. Or you can try it without "\bin" directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're pointing to the *bin* directory, which contains the tools but not the library and other files. Remove the "\bin" segment so that it's pointing to the actual Scala root directory and it should work.

Comment: When I point to: C:\Program Files (x86)\scala I get the following error:
Missing files:
scala-library-src.jar, scala-swing-src.jar, scala-actors-src.jar

Comment: @Marin that doesn't matter, it tells you it's missing the sources for the standard Scala libraries, but you don't really need those to use Scala in the IDE.

Comment: @Jesper will that error cause any trouble if I try to build any applications using Akka? :)

Comment: @Marin no, it simply means you won't be able to view the source code of the standard Scala library when working in your IDE. (I have some other minor problems with Scala and Akka in IntelliJ, but they're not caused by this).

Comment: NOTE: this is actually the default location that IDEA points to, not user error.

Answer (score 0):

As with `JAVA_HOME`, you want to point to the parent directory rather than the *bin* folder inside.